# How could I get a random string from a list and assign it to a variable

Tags: c#

My list is defined as:

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
```

When I add some strings to this list, how would I go about retrieving a random string from the list? Something like:

```
string currName = someFunctionOf (firstNames);
```

Comment: bonus points- make an extension method to do this!

Answer (score 24):

Here's a different approach than the three posted, just for some variety and fun with LINQ:

```
string aName = firstNames.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
```

Comment: -1 for obscurity, +1 for cleverness, and +1 for applying SQL tricks.

Comment: I would perhaps mention that this approach is hard to read, slow, and should not be used in real code.

Comment: @Eds but fun and quite clever

Answer (score 17):

Something like this?

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>( );
// add items to the list
Random r = new Random( );
int index = r.Next( myList.Count );
string randomString = myList[ index ];
```

Comment: Nope, the returned number is *less* than the argument.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
    List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
    firstNames.Add("name1");
    firstNames.Add("name2");
    firstNames.Add("name3");
    firstNames.Add("namen");

    Random randNum = new Random();
    int aRandomPos = randNum.Next(firstNames.Count);//Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum (firstNames.Count).

    string currName = firstNames[aRandomPos];
```

Comment: It should be 

 int aRandomPos = randNum.Next(firstNames.Count - 1);

Else you might get index out of range exception when the random number picks the maximum value.In Yourcase 4

Comment: @Jebli That's not correct- it returns a random number **less** than the maximum. So `randNum.Next(firstNames.Count);` works as expected.