# How can I pick a random string from a list and assign it to a variable C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, random

I am trying to make a program where the user enters a string and the string is then stored in a List named word1. I want to pick a random string from the List, and display it in a label. I'm trying to do this using multiple methods and classes as practice. Here's my code:

This is in the class Class1.cs:

```
    main main = new main();

    public string flashCards1()
    {
        List<string> word1 = main.GetList1();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int rtn = rnd.Next(word1.Count - 1);

        string word = word1[rtn];

        string rtnWord = word.ToString();

        return rtnWord;
    }
```

This one is in main.cs (not Main) and it talks to Class1. Like I said this part is probably unnecessary but I was trying to practice with multiple methods.

```
    private List<string> word2 = new List<string>();
    private List<string> word1 = new List<string>();

    public List<string> GetList1()
    {
        return word1;
    }

    public void SetList1(List<string> updatedList)
    {
        word1 = updatedList;
    }
```

This one is in Form1.cs and sets the label to the return value of flashCards1:

```
    private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        menu.Visible = false;
        cards.Visible = true;

        label1.Text = class1.flashCards1();

    }
```

This is also in Form1.cs and saves the text to the List:

```
    private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> word1 = main.GetList1();

        word1.Add(textBox1.Text);

        main.SetList1(word1);
    }
```

When I run this code it gives my the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146233086
>     Message='maxValue' must be greater than zero.
>   Parameter name: maxValue
>     ParamName=maxValue
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Random.Next(Int32 maxValue)
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1.flashCards1() in C:\Users\lottes\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Class1.cs:line 19
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.go_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\lottes\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 62
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\lottes\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

I've tried to enter lots of values but it doesn't seem to work. I also looked at this thread:
[How could I get a random string from a list and assign it to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753508/how-could-i-get-a-random-string-from-a-list-and-assign-it-to-a-variable)

However their solutions gave me the same error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this was too much/little information. I tried to make sense.

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile, let alone show a runtime error. You have to simplify your problem to a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that. Also, include the full error message including the stack trace. Don't just pick a few words out of an error message; every word means something. For example “'maxValue' must be greater than zero” probably means you have a variable named `maxValue` somewhere you haven't shown us that you haven't initialized.

Comment: Yes I know, I did not give the all of the code because it was quite a bit because i was practicing with different classes. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Also I did not see the copy to clipboard option for the exception, so I just copied what I thought I should've. I updated the post

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with the [Random.Next(int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This exception comes up when you try use a negative value as your maximum parameter. This is because it returns a value between `>= 0 and < maxValue`. Which gets messed up by negative values (-1 in your case when the list has 0 items)

The fix is easy, just change :

```
        int rtn = rnd.Next(word1.Count - 1);
```

into:

```
        int rtn = rnd.Next(word1.Count);
```

This should work because random always returns a value *less than* the maximum value, so should access 0 through N - 1, where N is the size of your list.

You're going to have further problems after that one (and less related to this direct question) though because the core issue is that you haven't initialized your list and added values before using it in the `flashcards1()` function. It's not clear how to solve that in the examples you've shown us, but I'd suggest looking at the order in which your functions execute.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you. I'll look at the order it runs in :)